# Should we allow poll questions?

Tags: discussion, poll

Like [this one](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/5/whats-your-favourite-flash-game)?

Or should them be closed?
EDIT:
[This question](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/1338/gaming/2586#2586) was deemed of topic in the definition phase, and it's very similar, so I voted to close

Comment: Based on your acceptance of my answer, should we begin closing these down?

Comment: I don't really know what accepting a question here should mean @Dr., I just wanted it to be on top because that's also my opinion, but it's not more valid than the opposite just because I asked the question.

Comment: @Juan: Do we have mods yet? I know this was your proposal; does that imply leadership? (Basically, I see a big old "close" button, ironically no "edit" ones outside of wiki, and have a huge urge to hit it on the polls/subjectives. But I also do not want to overstep my bounds nor start some of the wars that we've seen on Meta.SO without clear guidance ... In other words, I'm trying to be fair to all. :)

Comment: @Dr., no mods yet, I guess this is bootstrap mode. I never implied I was a leader of any kind just because I proposed it, I'll unaccept your answer if that's the message I'm conveying (I just wanted to agree with it)

Comment: No problema. No message was conveyed, BTW, I was just wondering if that was something the team was building into these systems. (I didn't propose any, so I wouldn't know! :) )

Comment: I'm guessing there'll be moderator nominations and votes when and if the site graduates from beta

Comment: Would changing the title of my question (What are good Flash games?) to "List of Flash games" be less subjective? There seems to be other threads that are subjective such as "What game offers the best co-op multiplayer experience?" (although the question allows people to explain why).

Comment: Whatever we do, we should do to all similar questions, like the one you mentioned Mew2468. My 0.02 would be that "List of Flash games" is better, but I'd argue that's more suited to an article in a wiki. The voting on the answers would still only be based on peoples' personal preferences. Just my 0.02, though.

Comment: Slightly off topic, but what is preferred on these Stack Exchange websites? Leaving questions closed or deleting them? I'm wondering what I should do with my question, because I agree with Dr. Gonzo's answer now.

Comment: @Mew, leave it closed as a placeholder/example for future discussions (at least during the beta)

Comment: @Mew2468: I think closure is probably appropriate. They can be deleted later (once we have mods or 10K users), but the truth is that having the closed, visible example can also serve as a deterrent to the new questioner. EG, when he asks why his was closed, we point out the old one and say, "we never allowed them."

Answer (score 14, accepted):

My theory on this is simple:

On StackOverflow, the early days allowed a certain amount of meta, poll and subjectivity in questions. As a result, in later months, after the system sorted itself out a bit better, newer users would point to those questions and then ask, "why was *mine* closed if programming jokes is still open?"

I would say the smart answer, if you don't want to be cleaning these up long-haul, is to nip them in the bud early, close them down, and get the rules straightened out clearly and succinctly.

Comment: I agree completely

Comment: my thoughts exactly

Comment: Perhaps we should allow a bunch of carefully crafted poll questions that cover some major topics, such as one recommendation thread for the main types of game.  I mean, we basically seed all the polls we will allow before the site leaves beta and those the only exception to the rule.  They can stay live and presumably they will continue to serve the purpose of the major potential poll questions indefinitely.

Answer (score 9):

No. They are a waste of time and don't relay anything useful.

Comment: This is my _real_ answer.

Answer (score 4):

I don't like this type of question. I would prefer something similar to:

> Can you list me some pro/cons of game
>   X, game Y and game Z because I cannot decide
>   which to buy.

Answer (score 1):

No. They should be closed, they only relay the **subjective** opinion of people. Especially the one you linked.

Yes if the question allow people to respond between **a few** choices and give pro/cons of their choice. like the one above or like

> What are the advantages of each class to level as fast as possible
>   a character in WoW ?

Answer (score 1):

I agree that subjective questions like mine are not very useful, but I think all these answers need somewhere to go, rather than have a bunch of different threads. For example, [is](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/101/lord-of-the-rings-online-tailoring-guide) [this](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/97/lord-of-the-rings-online-levelling-guide) [necessary](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/95/lord-of-the-rings-online-guardian-guide) [or](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/89/lord-of-the-rings-online-prospector-guide) [is](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/63/lord-of-the-rings-online-weaponsmithing-guide) [it](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/59/lord-of-the-rings-online-metalsmithing-guide) [also](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/51/lord-of-the-rings-online-minstrel-guide) [clutter](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/106/lord-of-the-rings-online-farmer-guide)?

Answer (score 1):

I think every site needs some (but **few**!) "rule breaking" questions, just to state we are not bureaucrats. And one mere distraction every now and then seems ok. I took a look at the programmers cartoon e.g., and I wasn't disturbed by it but I know I wouldn't try asking something even vaguely similar.

Answer (score 0):

It's just a variation of the subjective question so I'm inclined to say no. I like your answers though :)

Answer (score 0):

We won't be able to avoid these questions at the beginning, just like the "must have" on Super User.

I agree that we should keep them to a minimum, though. At least when all of them will be asked, we'll have a base to close as duplicate of.

Comment: Which is exactly why I posted one. This way anything that's remotely similar can get closed as a dupe. So instead of having 15 super broad ones, narrow them down and have them shut up afterwards

Answer (score -1):

Yes. Some people just cannot make decisions unless they know that at least 51% of people agree with them.

Answer (score -1):

It just occurred to me that this site is quite different from the original trilogy - it's about gaming. Gaming should be [**fun**](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/01/stack-overflow-where-we-hate-fun/). And fun involves checking new games, that others already know and can recommend (or not).

Therefore on a gaming site, *general* questions about *"which [flash, psx, ...] game is worth spending time/money for?"*, where the worthiness is indicated by upvotes, seems perfectly sensible to me.