# What about a way for people to rank/review games as a whole?

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, game-recommendations

I am constantly looking for reviews of games, and think there's a real opportunity to have users review games on here. I think a tag based system would work well, with each question being a call for the review of the game, and answers would be that users opinion of the game.

**[Update]**
I see that this has been totally misinterpreted - the examples in the answers are all about polls, which I also hate on SO/etc.

This is more like:

Q: Opinion on Mass Effect 2?
A: Love it because of a, b, c (+3)
A: Love it because of d (+1)
A: Hate it because of a, e (+4)

The fundamental failure with the system of SE is that it would violate the "every question must have an answer", but with a community like this, there is a real benefit to all users to have a structure opinion gathering outlet like this.

Answer (score 4):

This is definitely **not** a good idea. There have been dozens of posts on Meta regarding this subject, for example:

- [Should we allow poll questions?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5/should-we-allow-poll-questions)
- [Re-evaluating our site - what is the scope of an "acceptable" list, if it exists?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/624/re-evaluating-our-site-what-is-the-scope-of-an-acceptable-list-if-it-exists)
- [Best/favourite/subjective list type questions](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/475/best-favourite-subjective-list-type-questions)

A lot more are on Meta though. The point is that on the site we want answers that have a single right objective answer. Reviews are completely on the other end of the scope, they're the most subjective kind of questions we could post. The SO engine just doesn't lend itself to this properly, even if you use Community Wiki.

Besides, there are already plenty of sites where it's possible to post reviews, like [MetaCritic](http://www.metacritic.com/).

Comment: Besides, the StackExchange sites are Q&A sites, so we should be focusing on Q&A about gaming. I wouldn't categorize reviews as related to Q&A, as Arda has explained.

Comment: Wow, missed those earlier, but I totally disagree. If this is what the community wants, then fine, but I think this would be an ideal place to structure a very simple review system, that would be infinitely more useful than metacritic, since you'd have both reviews and a structure for agree and disagree. Oh well.

Comment: I see that this is totally misinterpreted, i will reword.

Answer (score 0):

Since this will always split up opinions I suggested [a separate place for polls](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57383/the-fourth-place-polling).